# Selecting dates from separate cells

Tags: excel, formula

I need to select a date from one of two cells. Example: Column A and Column B contain dates. If column A contains a date, I want it copied to column C; if B has a date, I want that date copied to C. If both A and B are blank, I want "NA" copied to column C. Only Column A OR B will contain a date. There will never be an instance where both column A and B contain a date.

Comment: Put your attempt in the question please. Also, can the columns A and B contain anything else than dates and blanks?

Answer (score 0):

If your column `C` has `Date Format`:

```
=IF(A1 & B1="","NA",MAX(A1,B1))
```

if not, you can next formula as well:

```
=IF(A1 & B1="","NA",TEXT(MAX(A1,B1),"dd.mm.yyyy"))
```

P.S. I assumed that your data in columns `A` and `B` can be only dates or empty

Comment: @pnuts, what you suggest? nested If? btw, there're many ways to do it. It's also possible to write `A1+B1`

Comment: @pnuts: Because it's fun! Weeeee. Simple formula requests like this are fun to turn into brain fuel. In the same way, why did I use `SUM` and `*1` when others will do. Harhar. :D

Comment: @pnuts, OP says that `There will never be an instance where both column A and B contain a date.` and I assumed that data in columns A and B can be only dates or empty. If it's not true - it would be a big formula with many ckeck -whether the data is number, or text, or date

Comment: @pnuts, I agree that formula won't work in that case, but I mentioned in my answer that I assumed that data in columns A and B can be only dates or empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `C`:

```
=IF(SUM(A1:B1)>0,(A1*1)+(B1*1),"NA")
```

Let us know if this helps. :)